# The front-end cannot accept the page returned by the back-end route

Tags: html, express, router

When the background route jumps to the front end to return to the page, it encounters the situation of downloading the page file。

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBV1i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWhpa.png)
When clicking  , the browser will download the post.html automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `res.send` or simply `res.sendFile` instead.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that when I add res.set('Content-Type','text/html;charset=utf-8') before res.render the front-end can get right response. I guess the default value for response Header is not the right option in res.render().